# How to create a always running PHP background script to clean up particular rows in mySql DB?

Tags: php, mysql

### How to create a always running PHP background script to clean up particular rows in mySql DB?

Hi guys I want to create a PHP script that automatically keeps on running  (for example after every hour) and delete some particular rows from database(for example user comments those are atleast 5 days older)for this I am already having the date column in table.

Please guide me how to do this as I am new to PHP.

Comment: In PHP is there something called background threads , just like we are having in .net.  Or Should we do this task by creating triggers in mySql database  ?

Comment: write your PHP script and setup cronjob every few minutes which executes you cleanup php script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are looking for is information on running some php maintenance scripts as a cron job.  How you do that will depend upon what type of server you are using, if you are using shared hosting or have a dedicated server.  In shared hosting there will be information about this on your control panel, otherwise you need to talk to your server admin.

Comment: I am having Amazon Cloud server , so i can install anything there.

Comment: So then you're the admin.  I am not familiar with how EC2 is set up, but you probably have shell account access to the server so you can use crontab  http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference to set up.  Just write your php scripts and set them to run in crontab.  Since you're on EC2 and paying for the time that you use, you might think about what the minimum frequency you need these to run actually is.

Comment: as i m developing on Windows machine so can i test these scripts on Windows?

Comment: I've only had a little experience here and mostly with websites.  There are difference between php on Windows and php on LAMP.  Anytime you are working with _SERVER[''] variables there are differences and there may be others.  You will probably have to do a bit of rewriting when you move it to the EC2 instance.  You might consider running a Unbuntu VM or live disk for local testing before you spend the $$ to push test code up to Amazon.

Answer (score 4):

For this, you can create a cron job, if you have access to the cpanel....
The cron jobs will run periodically, say for every minute, hour, day or week. Refer [**this**](https://kb.iweb.com/hc/en-us/articles/230244168-Setting-up-cron-jobs-with-cPanel-)

Comment: I am having Amazon Cloud server , so i can install anything there.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your PHP scrip that cleans up the mySql DB to run every hour or every mins/week/months with cron

[crone job basic](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

Comment: I am having Amazon Cloud server , so i can install anything there.